# Find the AutoCorrelation of a Random Process

Tags: probability, stochastic-processes, self-learning

Below is a problem I did where I suspect I missed something significant because it seemed to easy and my answer is way off.
Problem:
Consider a random process $X(y)$ defined by
\begin{eqnarray*}
 X(t) &=& Y \cos( wt + \Theta) \\
\end{eqnarray*}
where $Y$ and $\theta$ are independent r.v's and are uniformly distributed over $(-A,A)$ and $(-\pi,\pi)$, respectively. Find the autocorrelation function $R_x(t,s)$ of $X(t)$.
Answer:
\begin{eqnarray*}
R_{X_s\,X_t} &=& \frac{E( (X_t  - \mu_t)(X_s  - \mu_s ) ) } { \sigma_x \sigma_y } \\
\mu_t &=& E(X(t)) = E( Y \cos( wt + \Theta) ) \\
E(Y) &=& 0 \\
\mu_t &=& 0 \\
\mu_s &=& 0 \\
R_{X_s\,X_t} &=& \frac{E( (X_t  - 0)(X_s  - 0 ) ) } { \sigma_x \sigma_y } \\
R_{X_s\,X_t} &=& \frac{E( X_t X_s) } { \sigma_x \sigma_y } \\
E( X_t X_s) &=& E( Y \cos( wt + \Theta) Y \cos( ws + \Theta) ) \\
E( X_t X_s) &=& E(Y^2) E(\cos( wt + \Theta) \cos( ws + \Theta)  ) \\
\end{eqnarray*}
\begin{eqnarray*}
E(Y^2) &=& \int_{-A}^{A} y^2 dy = \frac{y^3}{3} \Big|_{-A}^{A} = \frac{2A^3}{3} \\
E(\cos( wt + \Theta) \cos( ws + \Theta)  ) &=& \frac{\cos( w(t+s) + 2\Theta ) + \cos(w(t-s))} { 2} \\
\end{eqnarray*}
\begin{eqnarray*}
E( X_t X_s) &=& \frac{A^3(\cos( w(t+s) + 2\Theta ) + \cos(w(t-s))} {6} \\
{\sigma_x}^2 &=& E(X(t)^2) - mu_t^2 = E(X(t)^2) \\
\end{eqnarray*}
\begin{eqnarray*}
E(X(t)^2) &=& E( Y^2 ) E( (\cos( wt + \Theta))^2 ) \\
E( (\cos( wt + \Theta))^2 ) &=& \int_{-\pi}^{\pi} (\cos( wt + \Theta))^2 \, dt \\
\text{Now we have the following standard integral to help up.} \\
\int \cos^2(ax) \, dx &=& \frac{x}{2} + \frac{\sin(2ax)}{4} + C \\
\end{eqnarray*}
\begin{eqnarray*}
\int_{-\pi}^{\pi} (\cos( wt + \Theta))^2 \, dt &=& \\
&& \frac{1}{w}\big(\frac{ wt + \Theta}{2} + \frac{\sin( 2( wt + \Theta) ) } {4}\big) \Big|_{-\pi}^{\pi} \\
\end{eqnarray*}
\begin{eqnarray*}
\int_{-\pi}^{\pi} (\cos( wt + \Theta))^2 \, dt &=&
 \frac{ t + \frac{\Theta}{w}}{2} + \frac{\sin( 2( wt + \Theta) ) } {4w} \Big|_{-\pi}^{\pi} \\
\frac{ t + \frac{\Theta}{w}}{2} \Big|_{-\pi}^{\pi} &=& \frac{\pi + \frac{\Theta}{2}}{2} -  \frac{-\pi + \frac{\Theta}{2} }{2} \\
\frac{ t + \frac{\Theta}{w}}{2} \Big|_{-\pi}^{\pi} &=& \frac{ \pi + \frac{\Theta}{2} + \pi - \frac{\Theta}{2} } { 2 } = \pi \\
\int_{-\pi}^{\pi} (\cos( wt + \Theta))^2 \, dt &=& \pi + \frac{\sin( 2( wt + \Theta) ) } {4w} \Big|_{-\pi}^{\pi} \\
\end{eqnarray*}
\begin{eqnarray*}
\int_{-\pi}^{\pi} (\cos( wt + \Theta))^2 \, dt &=&
 \pi + \frac{\sin( 2( \Theta) ) } {4w} - (  \frac{\sin( 2( \Theta) ) } {4w} ) \\
int_{-\pi}^{\pi} (\cos( wt + \Theta))^2 \, dt &=& \pi \\
E( (\cos( wt + \Theta))^2 ) &=& \pi \\
E(X(t)^2) &=& \frac{2\pi A^3}{3} \\
{\sigma_x}^2 &=& \frac{2\pi A^3}{3} \\
{\sigma_x}{\sigma_y} &=& \frac{2\pi A^3}{3} \\
R_{X_s\,X_t} &=& \frac{E( X_t X_s) } { \sigma_x \sigma_y }  \\
R_{X_s\,X_t} &=& \cos( w(t+s) + 2 \Theta ) + \cos( w(t-s) ) \\
\end{eqnarray*}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your definition of autocorrelation is wrong, i.e. $R_x(t,s) = E(X(t))E(X(s))$ is incorrect.

**Hints:**

$1:$ Use $$R_{X_t,X_s}(s,t)=\frac{E[(X_t-\mu_t)(X_s-\mu_s)]}{\sigma_{t}\sigma_{s}}$$

$2:$ Apply the fact that $Y$ and $\Theta$ are independent

$3:$ Conclude with $$\cos(x)\cos(y)=\left(\cos(x+y)+\cos(x-y)\right)/2.$$

Edit: Now your calculation for $E[cos(w(s+t)+2\Theta)]$ is not there. I just wrote it on a paper. See:[image]

Above I just omitted the scaling factor coming from the uniform density, i.e.

$$\int_{w(t+s)-2\pi}^{w(t+s)+2\pi} 1 dx=4\pi.$$ So you may want to replace $1/2$ terms with $1/8\pi$ but the result would again be $0$.

And dont forget: expectation is a linear operator so $$E[f(X)+f(Y)]=E[f(X)]+E[f(Y)]$$

> In your solution this part is wrong: $$E( (\cos( wt + \Theta))^2 ) = \int_{-\pi}^{\pi} (\cos( wt + \Theta))^2 \, dt $$

You take the expectation with respect to a random variable not a time variable. If you sum something over time, you will get the average of that something over a certain set or lets say an interval. You can correct this also via having a look at the JPG file that I put in to this answer.

$$E( X_t X_s) = E(Y^2) E(\cos( wt + \Theta) \cos( ws + \Theta)  )$$

$$E(\cos( wt + \Theta) \cos( ws + \Theta)  ) =E\left[ \frac{\cos( w(t+s) + 2\Theta ) + \cos(w(t-s))} { 2} \right]\\=E\left[ \frac{\cos(w(t-s))} { 2} \right]=\frac{\cos(w(t-s))} { 2} $$
Because, $$E\left[ \frac{\cos( w(t+s) + 2\Theta )} { 2} \right]=0$$
See the JPEG file I uploaded for how you get it.

Since $$E(Y^2) = \frac{1}{2A}\int_{-A}^{A} y^2 dy = \frac{1}{2A}\frac{y^3}{3} \Big|_{-A}^{A} = \frac{1}{2A}\frac{2A^3}{3}=\frac{A^2}{3}$$

We have

$$E( X_t X_s) = \frac{A^2}{3} \frac{\cos(w(t-s))} { 2}=\ \frac{A^2\cos(w(t-s))} {6}$$

Normally, to find the autocorrelation function one needs to normalize $E( X_t X_s)$ by $\sigma^2=\sigma_t\sigma_s.$ But from the answer that you had provided before I suspect that they are actually after $E( X_t X_s)$

You can find $$\sigma^2=E[Y^2]E[\cos(wt+\Theta)^2]$$

We already found $E[Y^2]$ and to find $E[\cos(wt+\Theta)^2]$ you will use the same tricks as in the JPEG file above. In particular $z=wt+\Theta\sim U[-\pi+wt,\pi+wt]$. Then,

$$E[\cos(wt+\Theta)^2]=E[\cos(z)^2]=\frac{1}{2\pi}\int_{-\pi+wt}^{\pi+wt} \cos(z)^2 \mathrm{d}z$$

I leave the rest to you. The solution was already there and you said "I give up"

Dont forget $$E[X]=\int x f_X(x)\mathrm{d}x$$ where $f_X$ is the density function of the random variable $X$.

In your solution you repeatedly did this wrong.

Comment: Do you agree with this: $Y$ and $\cos(wt + \Theta)$  are independent ; $E(Y) = 0$ ; $u_t = u_s = 0$?

Comment: @Bob your calculations or wrong. Please follow the guidelines in the answer and update your solution in the question. $E(Y)=0$ yes but where do you use this? $Y$ and $\cos(wt+\Theta)$ are indepdent. I dont know What $u_t$ and $u_s$ are.

Comment: $u_t$ and $u_s$ are the means of $X_t$ and $X_s$.

Comment: @seyhmum Gungoren is my assumption that $X_t$ and $X_s$ being independent wrong?

Comment: @Bob yes it is wrong in this example. $X_t=Y$ and $X_s=Y$ and $Y$ is indepdent of $Y$? what do you think? "I am indepdent of myself" does that make sound? why dont you write the equation? $ycos(..)*ycos(..)=y^2..$

Comment: I have updated my post based @Seyhmus Gungoren comments. I am hoping that somebody will tell me what I am still doing wrong. Thanks. Bob.

Comment: @Bob see the edit.

Comment: Gungoren I do appreciate the help you provided and I think you taught me something. However, I am giving up on this problem.

Comment: @Bob see the edit. I did it for you. Now you can write everything down and make a conclusion about your mistakes. If there are some points which you failed to understand just ask.

Comment: @seyhmum Gungoren I understand that $E[X] = x f_x(x) \m dx$ but I fail to find a place where I made a mistake using this formula in my original solution. Can you point it out to me? Thanks.

Comment: @Bob I did it already in my answer.. in particular all cases in your solution where you have $\int...\mathrm{d}t$.